# How to Group by Name in Treeview Control

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have been googling and searching youtube but find no answer, so I would like to ask for help in here.

I want to group the name in the TreeView control in VB, how can I do it?

Thank you

[image: Visual Studio Form GUI]
[image: Visual Studio Form GUI 2]

```
Public Class FrmPengingat

    Private Sub FrmPengingat_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DSLap.PengingatHutang' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.PengingatHutangTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DSLap.PengingatHutang)

        'fill the tree control
        Dim NmPemasok As String
        Dim NoNota As String
        Dim TglJatuhTempo As Date
        Dim Total As Decimal
        Dim tmpNmPemasok As String

        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To DSLap.PengingatHutang.Count - 1
            NmPemasok = DSLap.PengingatHutang.Rows(i).Item(0)
            tmpNmPemasok = DSLap.PengingatHutang.Rows(i).Item(0)
            NoNota = DSLap.PengingatHutang.Rows(i).Item(1)
            TglJatuhTempo = DSLap.PengingatHutang.Rows(i).Item(2)
            Total = DSLap.PengingatHutang.Rows(i).Item(3)

            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(i, NmPemasok).Nodes.Add(i, NoNota & " (" & TglJatuhTempo & ")   " & Total)

        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You need to set the `parent` this describes the relationship between the items. More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.parent(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DaveB : `Parent` is read-only. You cannot modify it, it's set automatically.

Comment: @VisualVincent Hi thank you for your answer, it solved :)

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
TreeView1.Nodes.Add(i, NmPemasok).Nodes.Add(i, NoNota & " (" & TglJatuhTempo & ")   " & Total)
```

adds a new parent node every time. You should check if the tree view already contains a node with the same text and only add a new one if it doesn't.

I suggest you make the key the same as the text for the parent node, that way it'll be easier to check if it exists or not.

Replace the above with this:

```
If TreeView1.Nodes.ContainsKey(NmPemasok) Then 'The parent node already exists.
    TreeView1.Nodes(NmPemasok).Nodes.Add(i, NoNota & " (" & TglJatuhTempo & ")   " & Total)
Else 'The parent node doesn't exist.
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(NmPemasok, NmPemasok).Nodes.Add(i, NoNota & " (" & TglJatuhTempo & ")   " & Total)
End If
```

Comment: It's not really a great idea to add nodes one by one. Better to create all the nodes first and then add them all in a single batch.

Comment: @jmcilhinney : Somewhat true, but if you were to suspend redrawing would it really make much of a difference?